# Import a library with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP (v3.0), and my Controller code is as below:

```
namespace App\Controller;

class ArticlesController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
        $context = new BLTI("secret", true, false);
    }
}
```

I want to create a `BLTI` object. I have a folder whose name is `ims` that contains the following PHP files:

- blti.php (contains two class, one of them is "BLTI")
- blti_util.php
- OAuth.php

I have placed this `ims` folder in `vendor` directory. My problem is that i don't know how I must import this `ims` folder in my Controller to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App::import() has been removed in CakePHP 3.0, so simply [require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the files and use the [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) statement to load the classes into your namespace.

Normally you would just add them to your [autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.html), but obviously these files and classes are pretty old and don't care about best practice (one class per file) or follow any convention for automated file loading.

You could change the files naming of that lib as well so that they can be used with the autoloader. Should be easy to do as well.